# How to create a langchain doc from an str?

Tags: python, nlp, langchain, large-language-model

I've searched all over langchain documentation on their official website but I didn't find how to create a langchain doc from a str variable in python so I searched in their GitHub code and I found this :

```
  doc=Document(
                page_content="text",
                metadata={"source": "local"}
            )
```

PS: I added the metadata attribute
then I tried using that doc with my chain:
Memory and Chain:

```
memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history", input_key="human_input")
chain = load_qa_chain(
    llm, chain_type="stuff", memory=memory, prompt=prompt
)
```

the call method:

```
  chain({"input_documents": doc, "human_input": query})
```

prompt template:

```
template = """You are a senior financial analyst analyzing the below document and having a conversation with a human.
{context}
{chat_history}
Human: {human_input}
senior financial analyst:"""

prompt = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=["chat_history", "human_input", "context"], template=template
)
```

but I am  getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'page_content'
```

when I tried to check the type and the page content of the Document object before using it with the chain I got this

```
print(type(doc))
<class 'langchain.schema.Document'>
print(doc.page_content)
"text"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue and I noticed the API calls for a list, so try

```
    doc = Document(page_content=input,
            metatdata={
                "source": "userinput"
            }
        )
    #db.add_documents(doc)
    db.add_documents([doc])
```

Answer (score 37):

This worked for me:

```
from langchain.docstore.document import Document

doc =  Document(page_content="text", metadata={"source": "local"})
```

Comment: It seems that importing from `langchain.schema.document` also works, and that latter module is the one specified in the [API documentation](https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/schema/langchain.schema.document.Document.html#langchain.schema.document.Document).

Answer (score 4):

First, some context. From what I've learned so far, a Document is a list of `Document` objects. If you run `type(doc[0])` you get `langchain.schema.document.Document`. This `Document` object is a dictionary made of two keys: one is `page_content:` which accepts string values, and the second key is `metadata:` which only accepts dictionaries. `{page_content: str, metadata: dict}`. By default (don't quote me on this: it's been lots of trial and error and, as you mentioned, there is no documentation), an "empty" `Document` contains the two mentioned keys, and a single dictionary in its `metadata:` with one key: `{source:}` that only accepts strings. You can create a multiple "page" Document object by creating a `list` of `Document` objects like so:

First, you must have a list of string texts: `text_list` below, and a list of dictionaries for the metadata: `text_list` below. **You must ensure both lists are the same length**.

```
from langchain.docstore.document import Document

document =  []

for item in range(len(text_string)):
    page = Document(page_content=doc_text_splits[item],
    metadata = metadata_string[item])
    doc.append(page)
```

Additionally, you can also create `Document` object using any splitter from LangChain:

```
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter

doc_creator = CharacterTextSplitter(parameters)

document = doc_creator.create_documents(texts = text_list, metadatas = metadata_list)
```

Comment: Useful info above regarding the text splitter, thanks.  In addition to the create_documents method, TextSplitter.split_documents() is also useful, as it creates 'bite size' documents that can be ingested by the LLM.

Answer (score 1):

Langchain's API appears to undergo frequent changes. While @Rahul Sangamker's solution remains functional as of `v0.1.11`, it may encounter compatibility issues due to the recent restructuring – splitting `langchain` into `langchain-core`, `langchain-community`, and `langchain-text-splitters` (as detailed in [this](https://blog.langchain.dev/the-new-langchain-architecture-langchain-core-v0-1-langchain-community-and-a-path-to-langchain-v0-1/) article). However, it's worth noting that these changes are backwards compatible.

Here's an updated solution, reflective of the `v0.1` style, now importing from `langchain_core.documents`.

```py
from langchain_core.documents import Document

doc = Document(page_content="text", metadata={"source": "local"})
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the best that I could come with

```
def str_to_doc(text,name):
   folder_name = 'docs'
   if not os.path.exists(folder_name):
       os.makedirs(folder_name)
   file_name = name+'.txt'
   path = os.path.join(folder_name, file_name)
   with open(path, "w") as file:
        file.write(text)
   loader = TextLoader(path)
   return loader.load()
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**